# Display image in android with spaces in filename from online

Tags: android, imageview

I need to display an image in my android application. The problem is I want to get this image from somewhere online. The URL is like:

> http://www.mydomain.com/hello world image.png

As you see the image name containing some spaces in it. Every time I execute my code this will show me exception of FileNotFound. and nothing happens.

Following is my code

```
String imagePathCon = "hello world image.png";      
String imagePath = "http://www.mydomain.com/" + imagePathCon;
try {
  URL url;
  url = new URL(imagePath);

  // url = new URL("http://www.azuma-kinba.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/Android-Make-Google-Loss-in-2010.png");

  InputStream content = (InputStream)url.getContent();
  Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(content , "src"); 
  im.setImageDrawable(d);

 } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

I use to replace space with "+" but nothing happens.

Comment: Are you getting image when you are hitting URL in Browser directly?

Comment: Try to encode URL, for example: `String encodedurl = URLEncoder.encode(url,"UTF-8");`

Comment: @zeeshan pls accept the Answer to whom you found helpfull

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work.

```
String imagePathCon = "hello world image.png";   
imagePathCon=imagePathCon.replaceAll(" ", "%20");

String imagePath = "http://www.mydomain.com/" + imagePathCon;
```

You must know http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Character_data

Answer (score 3):

plese use correct Url for getting image and use below code that would definetly help u...

replace space of URL using...

```
  imagePath=imagePath.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
```

and now...

```
         HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(new URL(params[0]).toURI());
         HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
         HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpClient.execute(httpRequest);
         HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
         BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity); 
             InputStream is = bufHttpEntity.getContent();
        //image_value = new URL("image Url is here");
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FlushedInputStream(is));
    //imageLoader is object of iamge view
           imageLoader.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Comment: Not working in my case. there is no exception now, but no image I got to display.

Comment: The code is working perfectly. by using String Replace to replace " " with %20.

Answer (score 0):

You need to url encode the path, like this:

```
String imagePathCon = URLEncoder.encode("hello world image.png", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: I change my line into:

`imagePath = "http://www.mydomain.com/" + URLEncoder.encode("hello world image.png"), "utf-8");`
          

IT still said File not Found.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an http get request:
The simplest way is to simply call URLEncoder which will automatically replace  all charaters in your string to the url encoded format.

```
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams(); 
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 30000); 
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 30000);
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters); 
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8"));
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpGet); 
in = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(); 
//Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(instream); 
//create a bitmap or an image from the input stream
```