# Get Bitmap from file path which contains whitespaces

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I need to display image from bitmap.It work well but when image with white name spaces not getting bitmap.

Following is my method  for getting bitmap from file path.

```
var bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                            mContext.contentResolver,
                            Uri.fromFile(File("" +imagePathCon))
                        )
```

While file with whitespaces name it gives null pointer exception for above line

Thanks

Comment: if you have an error (exception), please add it to the post

Comment: Pass the `File` to an image-loading library, such as Glide or Picasso. Or, use `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()`.

Answer (score 0):

Get the file name from the Uri using the `getScheme()`.

Then remove every whitespace from such a file name. This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10944400/8649647

Comment: It's working for URL image but not work with file path from internal storage

Comment: Try to get the file path, separate it from the file name. Let's say your file path is `/data/user/0/com.user/internal_storage/image name.png`, you need to get `image name.png` using the Uri `getScheme()`.